# Changing the table row height in all rows except the first row

Tags: tables

Is there a way to change the row height in a tabular environment in all rows except the first row? I want the rows, except the first one, to be of the same height.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\rule{0pt}{2cm}}ccc}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{a}&b&c\\
\hline
1&2&3\\
\hline
11&22&33\\
\hline
111&222&333\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```